# Filtering a list of areas with MapServer

Tags: mapserver

I have defined layer with filtering. I've used operator IN because I have list of values:

```
LAYER
  NAME "loc_mistnosti3"
  TYPE POLYGON
  ...
  FILTERITEM 'ID'
  FILTER ( [ID] IN %id% )
  VALIDATION
     "id" "[0-9]"
  END
```

URL address contains this list of values:

```
...layer=loc_mistnosti3&**id=180,214**&map_size...
```

but result is still:

> msCGILoadForm(): Web application error. Parameter 'id' value fails to validate.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Don't you need to URLEncode the commas within the list?

Comment: Because the value of id is `180,214` and your validatation pattern is `[0-9]`. There must be some fancy RegExp that accepts a list of numbers, separated by commas. Meanwhile you can validate anything with `*`.

Comment: I've tried possibly all but no success ... `[0-9\,]` - didn't work ... `[*]` - also didn't work. Answer is still `msCGILoadForm(): Web application error. Parameter 'id' value fails to validate. msApplySubstitutions(): Regular expression error. Parameter pattern validation failed.` or `msCGILoadForm(): Web application error. Parameter 'id' value fails to validate.`

Answer (score 2):

I believe your FILTER syntax is incorrect.  This is working for me (pay attention to the quotes in the FILTER) :

```
LAYER
  NAME "park"
  METADATA
    "wms_title"    "Parks"
  END
  DEBUG 5
  VALIDATION
    "code" "[0-9]"
  END    
  ..
  FILTER ("[reg_code]" IN "%code%")
  ...

END # Layer
```

You can test this outside the browser, at the commandline, such as:

```
mapserv -nh "QUERY_STRING=map=D:\ms4w\apps\stackexchange\filter-validation-364540\filter-validation.map&mode=map&layers=all&code=12,13" > ttt.png
```

Here is my parks layer in QGIS:

[image]

And here it is live on the MS4W demo server for you to try (try changing the end of the url to "code" values such as 24,12,13,0): [https://ms4w.dev/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\ms4w\apps\stackexchange\filter-validation-364540\filter-validation.map&mode=map&layers=all&code=12,13](https://ms4w.dev/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:%5Cms4w%5Capps%5Cstackexchange%5Cfilter-validation-364540%5Cfilter-validation.map&mode=map&layers=all&code=12,13)     (MapServer 7.6)

Hope that helps.

(by the way, I just now added this commandline trick to the MapServer docs at https://mapserver.org/mapfile/validation.html )

-jeff

Comment: It looks simply. I've checked and updated my definition of localization layer according to your definition - no succes. If I put only one value `212` into variable `id` in URL so everything is OK - map is generated. If I put two values `212,213` so result is `msCGILoadForm(): Web application error. Parameter 'id' value fails to validate.`. **It looks like some problem with separator.**

Comment: I've tried crazy thing ... I've put values directly into layer definition into `FILTER` - here is my definition `FILTER ("[ID]" IN "212,213")` and it's OK - it works and map is generated with two highlighted areas! So It has to be problem with value separator during validation process.

Answer (score 2):

BINGO!!!

So. My variable called **id** and it is the problem!

```
...&layer=loc_mistnostiT&id=212,213...
```

Definition of VALIDATION in LAYER looked like this:

```
  VALIDATION
   "id" "[0-9]"
  END
```

So I have looked into **mapservutil.c** and there is this:

```
    if(strcasecmp(mapserv->request->ParamNames[i],"id") == 0) {
     if(msEvalRegex(IDPATTERN, mapserv->request->ParamValues[i]) == MS_FALSE) {
       msSetError(MS_WEBERR, "Parameter 'id' value fails to validate.", 
       "msCGILoadForm()");
       return MS_FAILURE;
     }
     strlcpy(mapserv->Id, mapserv->request->ParamValues[i], IDSIZE);
     continue;
    }
```

It is answer which I got every time during my trying to solve my problem. And **id** in this code looked a bit suspiciously.

So I've changed my variable **id** to **xid** and everything is OK now!!!

My new definition is:

```
  VALIDATION
   "xid" "[0-9]"
  END
```

... and variable in URL is (**id renamed to xid**):

```
...&layer=loc_mistnostiT&xid=212,213...
```

Comment: So in summary, there were 2 issues regarding your original question:
 1) your FILTER syntax was incorrect, and never would display your results, as I mentioned in my answer, you are missing the quotes such as `FILTER ("[reg_code]" IN "%code%")`
   and 2) you cannot use the`id` variable name, good catch, I've added this as a note at the bottom of https://mapserver.org/mapfile/validation.html

Comment: And finally, for good karma and to help give back to the free software that you are relying on, please create a Pull Request to help improve the MapServer documentation, at https://github.com/mapserver/docs    Thanks!